# How can I show data that i just get from an httpClient.get() in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I just want to retrieve data from an external API and then show this data. The problem I think is the fact that I get this data "too late", I mean in my code I try to visualize this data before those data are ready. This is probably due to the fact that HttpClient.get() is asynchronous.

1) Service:

```
getListaMetroObservable(): Observable<Metro[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.api)
    .map(this.mapper)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private mapper(current) {
    console.log(current); // I see data here
    return current as Metro[];
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
```

2) component that use that service:

```
constructor(private service: MyserviceService) {
    this.listametro = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListaMetroObservable();
    console.log(this.listametro); // I get empty array
    this.metro = this.listametro[0];
  }

  getListaMetroObservable() {
    this.service.getListaMetroObservable()
      .subscribe(
        risp => this.listametro = risp,
        error => this.errorMsg = error
      );
  }
```

3) in the template of the component:

```
<p>element: {{metro.idt}}</p>
```

I'd like to see the first element of the array "listametro". I get null due to the fact that I don't have any element in the array. How can I solve this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: the idea of promises are extremely important when fetching data from api endpoints. learn more about it here https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-promises/. when using a promise, you can put the body of the code that uses the expected return value from the api so that it does not execute until the request has returned with that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use async pipe and avoid subscription, using async pipe will unsubscribe automatically for you,  try this:
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

```
listametro: Observable<Metro[]>

constructor(private service: MyserviceService) {
  this.listametro = this.service.getListaMetroObservable();
}
```

and display it that way in your template

```
<p>element: {{(listametro | async)[0]?.idt}}</p>
```

Comment: this.listametro = this.service.getListaMetroObservable();

In this line I have this problem:

Type 'Observable<Metro[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Observable<Metro[]>>'

Comment: fixed, check it ,  listametro: Observable<Metro[]>

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
  getListaMetroObservable() {
    this.service.getListaMetroObservable()
      .subscribe(
        risp => this.listametro = risp,
        error => this.errorMsg = error
      );
  }
```

Into this:

```
  getListaMetroObservable() {
    this.service.getListaMetroObservable().subscribe(result=>{
         console.log(result)
         this.listametro = result
      },error=>{
         console.log(error);
       });
  }
```

And tell me what you see in this line `console.log(result)`

Comment: I see the data as expected

Comment: well there you go. actually before you were doing a console.log without waiting your Observable to resolve. => stuff to do with your data need to be inside the subscribe callback function

Comment: I don't understand what to do. Could you write it more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

What you do on `ngOnInit()` will not wait for the code executed in the `subscribe()`. That explains why your console does't print anything.

Same for when you assign`this.metro` it's not in the `subscribe()`, even tho you call it after the `getListaMetroObservable()` call, it won't wait for the subscription itself.

Try something like this:

```
  getListaMetroObservable() {
    this.service.getListaMetroObservable()
      .subscribe(
        risp => 
        {
          this.listametro = risp;
          console.log(this.listametro);
          this.metro = this.listametro[0];
        },
        error => this.errorMsg = error
      );
  }
```